# single line group of commands as individual?

Tags: command-line, bash

I made one small alias and got a question as , how to execute a single line group of commands as command by command with out breaking it ?

```
echo " alias get='sudo apt-get install'" >> .bashrc & bash
```

here we have commands as echo & bash. even placing them all in a single line i want to execute them command by command.

Update: for example if there is a group command line as

command1 ; command 2; command 3; command 4; commmand5

Then I want to execute this group command not in a single step. 1st 3 commands at a time and then next 2 commands . But condition is I have to write all those commands in a single line.

Comment: You will execute them "command by command" unless you run them in parallel by sending one to the background with `&`. Otherwise, the shell will execute the commands sequentially.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to ask here, @Jai - could you try and explain more thoroughly exactly what you would like to do, please?

Comment: Dinner time- Delay ,sorry. I am trying to execute only a part of the total command and not the total group of commands at a time. my choosing part may include a single command or more. I need to select specific part of the total command for execution.

Comment: Do you mean by using command grouping in Bash?, like `cmd || { cmd; cmd; }`

Comment: @Mik Thanks for responding. I will try to explain more about my Question.

Comment: Probably, the only way to do it would be to use command grouping in {}. i.e. `{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }; sleep 10; { cmd4; cmd5; }` Thereby you could execute them in groups and put a pause between them and keep them all on the same line.

Comment: could you add it as a answer and elaborate it more with more data ? Because waiting for 10 sec is no needed , I mean If press Enter only 3 commands  have to execute and for the remaining two commands I need to give one more enter and all those commands should be in a single line.

Comment: Ok, for you to get a second enter to confirm the execution of the last two commands I would need to put some extra logic in between the command groups like read -p....., but it should work and should still be on one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do what you have in mind by using command grouping, which allows you to execute commands together, in this case, whether they succeed or not, i.e. in the form `{ cmd; cmd; }`. More information on command grouping and the use of && and || logical operators is available at [the Bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/017) and in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping).

I thought initially the form your command-line could take would be:

```
{ cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; }; sleep 1; { cmd4; cmd5;}
```

The sleep command just gives a pause and can be removed.

**However**, you say you want an extra return, or confirmation for the last two commands, and so to achieve that you need to interrupt the command flow in the example above- sleep merely pauses, but regardless the last two commands always execute.

To really halt the command chain, you could use `read -p.....` which requires user intervention to continue. Here is what you could do:

1) Execute the first three commands, then give the user the opportunity or not to execute the last ones. You could see if the oneliner I have written below is suitable:

**Note**: Please substitute the id command for your own commands.

```
id; id; id; read -p "Execute final two commands? (Y/N) " ans; if [[ $ans =~ Y|y ]]; then id; id; else echo "Finished"; fi
```

Now the first three commands execute and then you need to press y and return for the last two to execute, but all the commands are on the same line. This is about as much as I can contrive really, as I am not quite sure what you want.

Comment: you gave something I really needed. Thank you. I will modify it as I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`&` runs the left hand side command in the background. If you want to run the second command only if the previous one ran successfully, use

```
 command1 && command2
```

If you want to run the second command even if the previous one is not successful, use

```
command1 ; command2
```

Comment: I mean as Not the total line . only a part of the line. only a few commands. not all the commands existed in that line.

Comment: @Jai: Please give more details. I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

echo " alias get='sudo apt-get install'" >> .bashrc **&&** bash

Just put 2 ampersands and it works.

Comment: I mean as Not the total line . only a part of the line. only a few commands. not all the commands existed in that line.

Comment: are you just trying to execute the echo command in the bash shell because you don't currently use bash?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run them in sequence, the best way would be to use the double ampersand `&&`. This is often used, for example, when running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

The `&&` requires that the first command runs successfully before starting the second. So in the example I gave, it updates the package list, and then upgrades packages but only if the updating was successful.

The single ampersand is useful if you want to orphan a program from its terminal, so that the program stays open even if the active terminal is closed, by using e.g. `nautilus & disown`.

Comment: I mean as Not the total line . only a part of the line. only a few commands. not all the commands existed in that line.

Comment: @Jai Not sure I understand. Do you want it to run one, then wait for you to confirm before it runs the second?